# inotifywait in docker-container doesn't register changes

Tags: docker, inotify, boot2docker, inotifywait

I have a script running inside a docker-container which listens for changes in a directory via `inotifywait`. The directory is mounted to the host-system via `docker -v`.

For some reason, inotifywait doesn't get triggered when files inside this directory is changed.

This is the problematic script-line

```
inotifywait -e create -e modify -e delete -e move  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

The container is started like this (via fig)

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "80:80"
  volumes:
   - ./conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

When I start the setup via `fig up`, the script is executed, but changes in the mounted volume don't trigger the inotify-barrier.

Comment: I checked with a basic container, installed inotify-tools, started inotify, created a directory and a file, and was notified. So it seems related to volumes with `docker -v`

Comment: docker != virtualization, maybe this is an edgecase where docker can't keep the isolation up.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior using docker compose's (fig) volumes which are created with `docker -v`.

Comment: Five years later and this still doesn't work on docker edge with WSL2, linux container and mounted volume... Can't do react development with hot module replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add -mq to your script like this:

```
inotifywait -mq -e create -e modify -e delete -e move  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

I have tested this solution and it works. The "m" is for "monitor" and "q" is for quiet.

Comment: It depends on what you want, if you want inotifywait to stop watching after a change occurred you don't want the -m option. So for example if you have a script like:

`inotifywait <directory> && echo "Change detected"`

you don't want the -m option because it will wait forever and never get to the echo statement.